# Trigger programmatically autocomplete event for shell in system call and get output

Tags: bash, perl, shell, webmin, bash-completion

Before actual question few words about what I'm doing to grasp the idea.

I would want to add another cool feature to my *[Authentic Theme](https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme)* for *Webmin*.

I have made *Command Shell* module look/feel just if it was [ordinary shell](https://rostovtsev.ru/pub/src/authentic/18.40b/shell_port_demo.webm). However, as it's only a port, it has few limitations. One of them is missing shell *autocomplete*, when you hit `Tab` key (or other based on the system: `Esc+Esc` and/or `Ctrl+I`).

My point is to make it work natively. I'm going to use an
`XMLHttpRequest`
call to the server and pass the part of entered command to the actual shell. The call will be triggered on the event of the `Tab` key.

For example, when you're in *Authentic Theme* dropdown shell (you could see it on the video screencast above), and when you type, let's say, `xa` and hit `Tab`, the event will be triggered and make a request. Then the server receives a string `xa` and we're ready to begin.

#### My question<s>s are</s> is:

<s>1. What is the best way to execute such command in *Perl*?</s> 
<s>2. How to properly escape such command to make sure that it won't be exploitable;</s>
3. How to **trigger programmatically** `Tab` key (to run autocomplete) in the `system()` call;
<s>4. How to grep output.</s>

On the respond, using `xa` as an example, I expect to get `xargs` on the results.

---

I'm aware about possibly of ambiguity of the passed command, for example, when using `sys`, and when autocomplete wouldn't work on the single `Tab` key. I think it's better to exclude this from the scope of current question.

Comment: Split it into multiple questions. In its _current form_ it will not attract proper answers. Cheers!

Comment: @Inian, thank you for your advice but it's all interconnected. However, my real obstacle is number **3** and having an answer for `how to trigger it programmatically`, would be enough for me.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you actually need to do.  To catch a `TAB`, if that's what you mean, you need to handle keyboard events, for example by [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/TermReadKey-2.37/ReadKey_pm.PL). As for handling strings, there are for example  [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/~rwstauner/String-Substitution-1.002/lib/String/Substitution.pm) and  [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/String-Interpolate-0.32/lib/String/Interpolate.pm), which pays a lot of attention to security

Comment: @zdim If you go to ordinary shell and try to use autocomplete feature by using `Tab` key, you will see how it works. When you type `xa` and hit tab, you will get `xargs`. My point is to pass `xa` to the shell, trigger tab and get output. It's that fancy because of the currently imposed limitations.

Comment: @zdim for example, when using `system()` how would I do that. How would I pass `xa` to it, trigger `Tab` and get `xargs` as a results?

Comment: Have a look at [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu) it provides an interface to the Gnu Readline completion functions.

Comment: Ah ... how about printing the ANSI sequence for it?  If that satisfies the "pass to the shell".  I do know and use and love autocompletion, many many times every day :)  I sometimes even name my own programs so that it can be done early on while typing their names :)

Comment: Hm, I don't know how to or whether one can  do that.  But @HåkonHægland's remark is spot on -- why not write your own readline? The module is excellent (it's a whole suite)

Comment: @zdim thanks. @HåkonHægland I have never used/heard about `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`. You guess or you sure that it's possible to do using this module? By the way, when type `@usern...` in this comment box, it also has autocomplete feature. :)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev `Term::ReadLine::Gnu::completion_matches()`, or alternatively the Bash command [`compgen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) should both be able to give a list of possible completions given the word `xa` for example

Comment: @HåkonHægland, really cool, thanks a lot, **Håkon**.
@zdim - thanks for pointing out `Term::ReadKey.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the type of completion you want to generate, you can generate completions using the `compgen` bash builtin.

Most usefully, the `-c` option will complete command names and `-o default` will complete filenames through readline. See the [options for `complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-complete), most of which you can also use with `compgen`.

Note that `system()` will pass the command to `/bin/sh -c`, which may not be the same as `bash` on your system.  So you can do something like:

```
system('bash', '-c', 'compgen -c -- "$1"', 'bash', 'xa')
# xargs
# xattr
# etc…
```

or

```
system('bash', '-c', 'compgen -o default -- "$1"', 'bash', 'file')
# file.txt
# file.pdf
# etc…
```

---

If you want to literally the same thing that bash would do given a particular string (and not guess the completion type yourself), you will need to actually invoke the tab-press (or equivalent), which you can do with an `expect` script. This is also the only way to properly invoke any custom completion functions you may have defined. See for example the way that bash-completion handles [its test suite](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/test/lib/library.exp).

Below is my attempt at an `expect` script to print out the completions that bash would suggest for arbitrary command input:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/env expect

log_user 0
set prompt {/@}
set cmd [lindex $argv 0]

# start bash with no startup files for clean env
spawn env INPUTRC=/dev/null PS1=$prompt bash --norc
expect $prompt

# set some readline variables for consistent completion output
send "bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'\r"
expect $prompt
send "bind 'set bell-style none'\r"
expect $prompt
send "bind 'set completion-query-items -1'\r"
expect $prompt
send "bind 'set page-completions off'\r"
expect $prompt
send "bind 'set completion-display-width 0'\r"
expect $prompt

# run the completion
send "$cmd\t $prompt"
expect {
   # multiple matches, printed on separate lines, followed by prompt
   -re "^$cmd\r\n(.*)\r\n$prompt$cmd" { puts $expect_out(1,string) }
   # single match, completed in-place
   -re "^($cmd\[^ \]*)  $prompt" { puts $expect_out(1,string) }
   # single match, completed in-place, nospace
   -re "^($cmd\[^ \]+) $prompt"  { puts $expect_out(1,string) }
   # no match
   -re "^$cmd $prompt" { exit }
}
```

Calling `./script.exp string` will print out the actual completions that bash will produce for `string`, one per line. If there are no completions suggested, nothing is printed.

Comment: Yes, that what I was doing right now after reading comments to my question. Thanks, Grisha. :) We definitely need to escape input, e.g. `xa` to prevent injections. The only real problem is that I don't want to specify any params and would want `compgen` to guess, if it's a file or command or anything else (this is what hitting Tab does). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sadly there's no way to do that other than literally having bash do it.  I've updated the answer with an `expect` script, which is what the bash-completion uses to trigger real completions for testing.